# Monitor python code to check where the process are created

Tags: python, multithreading, process

When I execute my app I can see multiple process are running for my application. But I am not explicitly any process nor do I remember any call that I am making can create a process. Is there any way to monitor app such I it would point me to line where the process are created in python

```
import os
import threading
import time

sessionSweeperTime=5

def remove_idle_session():
    threading.Timer(sessionSweeperTime, remove_idle_session).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Remove idle session pid : {}, ppid : {}".format(os.getpid(), os.getppid()))

time.sleep(5)
print("Main pid : {}, ppid : {}".format(os.getpid(), os.getppid()))
remove_idle_session()
time.sleep(5)
print("pid : {}, ppid : {}".format(os.getpid(), os.getppid()))
# server started
```

## This is my output

```
Remove idle session pid : 18924, ppid : 18921
Remove idle session pid : 18945, ppid : 18924
Remove idle session pid : 18950, ppid : 18924
Remove idle session pid : 18947, ppid : 18924
Remove idle session pid : 18942, ppid : 18924
```

I am using ubuntu:18:04 inside a docker container

Comment: `threading.Timer` creates a thread object. Every time you call the `start` method on a `Thread` object (like `threading.Timer`) you are creating a new thread.

Comment: yeah but thread does not give different process id.

Comment: Sure, but you said " I am not explicitly [creating?] any thread nor do I remember any call that I am making can create a thread",  and I am pointing out that you *are* explicitly creating a thread.

Comment: Additionally, I am unable to reproduce the output you show in your question: when I run your code, `ppid` and `pid` remain constant. Maybe you can tell us more about the environment in which you are running this code...is it Linux? What distribution/version? Windows?

Comment: oh, sorry for that it was meant to be  `process` not thread

Comment: I am using ubuntu:18:04

Comment: I just set up a system with ubuntu:18.04 and I can't reproduce it there, either. See [here](https://asciinema.org/a/ezJqH7gy8RClazT5HJmSKvREt) for my complete attempt.

Comment: hmm... Looks like something else might be broken on my side. Do you know any way If I can where process are created.

Comment: Oh, I see you've updated your question to mention that you're running inside Docker. What OS is your *host* running?

Comment: host is `ubuntu.18.04`